# How to overload typescript's `path.normalize` definition?

Tags: typescript

I'm converting a flow project to TS, and one thing we have is a bunch of opaque types, e.g. `fileName`, `relativePath`, and `absolutePath`.  In flow we then overload `path` to use these types:

```
declare module 'path' {
  declare function normalize(path: absolutePath): absolutePath;
  declare function normalize(path: string): relativePath;
```

I'm trying to do the same in TS, but can't figure out how to either a) replace the existing `path` definitions (I'm good copying the 3 files we do this on) or b) merge my definitions into the existing ones.  No matter what I try it uses the ones from `@types/node` (though VS code shows that TS sees the 2 files, it always picks that one).  <s>I suppose I could just remove that and copy everything but I'd rather not for upkeep</s>.  I can't even copy & remove `@types/node` because other things include it, it'd just be a complete mess.

Minimal example (structure taken from the existing `path.d.ts` file):

```
declare module 'path' {
  namespace path {
    interface PlatformPath {
      normalize(p: absolutePath): absolutePath;
    }
  }
  const path: path.PlatformPath;
  export = path;
}

declare module 'node:path' {
  import path = require('path');
  export = path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself for reference:

I was trying to copy the way the `@types/node` file did this, which didn't work.  Just exporting an interface works:

```
declare module 'path' {
  export interface PlatformPath {
    normalize(p: absolutePath): absolutePath;
    normalize(p: string): relativePath;
  }
}
```